# How do Cancel type spells work in Rolemaster?

Tags: spells, rolemaster

Can someone please give an explanation on how a Cancel Essence or Cancel Channeling spell would work in the Rolemaster system?

By my reading, it seems like they are quite useless in a combat situation as you need to be aware that you are the target of a spell in order to cast and maintain it. Whilst you are maintaining the spell, you cannot cast any other spell or do any other offensive action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rolemaster RM/RM2/RMC**

**Cancel Essence/Channelling is for instant magic defense**

Cancel Essence/Channelling seem pretty useless until you consider their most important factor; they are ***Instantaneous*** spells, this makes them class I spells and they require no preparation no matter what level you are.

> **Cancel Essence** When a spell of the Essence realm is cast
>   against the caster (of cancel Essence) the attack spell must first
>   make a successful RR before the caster is forced to make a RR.

So this is a defensive spell to save the caster from being blasted; the first key combat stages in Rolemaster are:

1. Spell Phase
   All combatants who will cast or prepare spells during the round must specify any pertinent information (spell type, target area, etc)
2. Spell Results Phase
   All spells specified in the previous phase are resolved *simultaneously* unless an exception is indicated by the GM.

Here is an example combat where Wizard Bob faces his arch-rival Wizard Anti-Bob.

1. Spell Phase
   **Anti-Bob:** I shall blast Bob with a shock bolt
   **Bob:** I shall cast Cancel Essence
2. Spell Results Phase
   **Anti-Bob:** I blast Bob! Hahaha!
   **Bob:** My cancel essence spell spell is up! Make a RR to make your attack.
   **Anti-Bob:** <rolls and fails the RR> Curse you Wizard Bob!

This is the standard Rolemaster turn sequence from RMSS and RMC; this is of course complicated by the many different variants available through the Rolemaster Companions, but essentially all Instantaneous spells are reactionary spells (Like Bladeturn for example) that are there to save you from an attack or situation.

Note: In my games I used the standard AD&D style turn sequence: roll for initiative and each acts in turn. I let casters cast Instantaneous spells out of turn (using their spell up for that round) if they wished to react to something, it worked very well.

**Rolemaster Standard System**

The spells can still be used for instant defence - if you're a good enough caster.

All the spells on the "Dispelling Ways" (p16 Of Essence, p83 Spell Law) are no longer instantaneous, which means most of the spell list is now of dubious usefulness unless you're high enough level or take a penalty to cast them with zero round of preparation. For a same level spell this is a -55 to cast (spell casting modifications table T-4.6, p. 47 "Rolemaster fantasy Roleplaying) which isn't that bad a penalty if you're a good caster, long as you don't fail!)

"Cancel Essence" in Spell Wall (p14 Of Essence p81 Spell Law) and "Cancel Channeling" in Spell Defense (p14 Of Channelling) are all the same, so this isn't a typo/misprint it's an intended system change.

I can't say *why* ICE made this change, what I can say is that the change makes the spells pretty useless/more dangerous at low level as you'll have to fast-cast them. So I agree, as is, the spell is pretty pointless - I'd revert the change and make them instantaneous.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Where is it specified that this spell is instantaneous? In the Essence Companion,  under the Dispelling Ways list,  Cancel Essence is listed as a Force Spell with no indication that it is instantaneous. Normally,  instant spells have an asterisk on them.

Comment: Yes; it's a * to indicate a instantaneous spell. I was referring to Dispelling Ways in Spell Law; Are you using RMSS then?

Comment: In Spell Law the list "Dispelling Ways" EVERY spell in the spell list is Instantaneous except for Unessence/Unchanneling/Unmentalism; I'll dig out my copy of Essence Companion and see what's changed - could be a misprint or something else.

Comment: I'm using Rolemaster FRP: Spell Law - Of Essence

Comment: Checked my books; updated for RMSS and RMC and split the answer for both

Comment: Thanks for all your help - I've discussed it with the GM and since we already have some house rules for our game (it is supposedly magick-lite), he's agreed to revert to the instantaneous cast =) 
Also, glad to find someone else still familar with Rolemaster!

Comment: Rolemaster was the first RPG I ran, still love it :)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have the system (and not many others, judging by a month without an answer), I'm not sure which rules version this question relates to, and no excerpt/explanation of the spells and magic mechanics are given, I've found a house rule on page 8 of [Jörg Jahnke's Rolemaster House-Rules](http://joergjahnke.bplaced.net/Files/Rolemaster/RMHouseRules_en.pdf) relating to "Cancel Channeling spell of the Cleric" that sounds similar to your query:

> The 'Cancel Channelling' spell of the Cleric has a duration of 1
>   min/lvl instead of, as listed in Spell Law, a duration of 'C'. 
>   (Background: The same spell also exist, also at 2nd level, on the
>   Paladin Base Spell Lists and also on the Priest lists in Channelling
>   Companion. In both cases it has a duration of 1 min/lvl. There is no
>   obvious reason why it shouldn't have the same duration for the Cleric,
>   especially as the spell seems quite useless if concentration is
>   required.)

There might be an errata that could help, somewhere, or you could house rule to make the spell more useful like the above. Regarding the requirement of knowing you're the target of a spell in order to cast "cancel", it sounds like it fits the reactive-sounding nature of the spell; are there alternative spells that can be cast pre-emptively, to reduce success chance for a given type of spell? E.g. "I think I might be going into a room with water nymphs, I'll cast 'protection from water spells'"?

The main consensus I've noticed from my looking into this is that Rolemaster is the kind of old, complicated system where little niggles/minor broken things haven't been ironed out completely, even in later versions; some common sense/house ruling seems to be required to keep the system running smoothly.

Sorry if this isn't the kind of answer you were hoping for, but I don't know the system beyond freely available internet articles.

Comment: Thanks for that. We use rolemaster as the base, but have house-ruled a number of things to make things flow much easier. The world our campaign is set in is magic-lite and so we haven't really delved too deeply in to the magic rules. 
In regards to alternative spells to cast pre-emptively, yes there is, but they only affect a certain sub-class of spells (namely, elemental spells such as fire bolt, lightning bolt etc). Cancel Essence is supposed to be 'the spell' giving you an additional resistance roll against a spell.
I will show this answer to my GM and see what he says. Thanks again =)

Answer (score 0):

In the RMSS, you are correct, the cancel spells are there to provide a 'turtling' defense against incoming spells, for as long as the caster concentrates. This is limited, but could be used by the character being 'bait' for a hostile spell caster. As usual with Rolemaster, there are many alternatives: Protection and Resistance spells, which give bonuses to RR's, or the Spell Reins Closed Essence list which provides Spell Hold, which is instantaneous, and has a similar effect, with some interesting potential consequences. If that makes Spell Reins look overpowered compared with Dispelling Ways, I would argue that the point of Dispelling ways is the 'Dispel' series of spells, and the Cancel's are just there as a warm-up.